# Parallel I/O read files from disk in R

Tags: r, io, parallel-processing

I happen to have a large number of files to read and process in R (~20000 files, total ~40gb)

I was thinking about paralellizing the read; yet one phylosophical question comes to my mind regarding parallelizing. Perhaps the question is just wrong and my wording is not correct since I am not expert on the subject, so please correct me where I am wrong : Even with parallelizing, the disk reader pin still needs to access the file sequentially (there is only one reader head traversing the disk). We are parallelizing the cpu process, but would at any point the fact that mechanical reading becomes a hinder on the CPU parallelizing ? Will separating the files into clusters help the read, as we are trying to parallelize the physical read as well ?

Comment: What kind of files are that? If you can use `data.table::fread` you can read them in very fast without parallelization.

Comment: pdf and not text file nor csv. I'll download/read then process etc.

Comment: We don't have specs on the system, RAM config, i/o config, any current benchmark tests or profiling output (to be sure that i/o is indeed the bottleneck).

Comment: Let's say a typical good-enough laptop machine nowadays 16GB RAM, 1T SATA2 or less in SSD, Windows OS, chip intel i7 4 or 8-core. What would be the bottleneck, the disk read or the CPU for parallelizing ?

Comment: Are you reading from spinning disks?  If so, if parallelizing your read operations will cause parallel read attempts to the same spinning pysical disk(s), you will actually wind up going *slower* as the disk[s] will spend more time seeking.